# What obfuscation is this?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am currently a student working on a topic related to internet links and found this :

```
&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#115;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#105;&#110;&#102;&#111;&#112;&#97;&#121;&#112;&#97;&#105;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#47;
```

When I put this set on the browser's search bar or when I copy it paste here it puts a link:
https://verinfopaypai.com/

This link is not mine and I am not linked to this link, I stumbled upon it by chance.
Is there any way to find out what obfuscation it is?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Character 104 in ASCII is `h`, 116 is `t` etc etc you can see what it forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really obfuscation it's simply html entity encoding.

Each `&#{number};` block represents a character in html.

You can see more about this here. https://mothereff.in/html-entities